# Cannot compile C++ code whilst building image, but can after container is running?

Tags: c++, docker, tensorflow, g++

I am attempting to dockerize a github repository ([KPConv](https://github.com/HuguesTHOMAS/KPConv)). This repository houses code to architect and train a neural network model in `tensorflow`. This model implements its own [custom tensorflow operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op) in C++; [KPConv/tf_custom_ops](https://github.com/HuguesTHOMAS/KPConv/tree/master/tf_custom_ops). It provides a bash file to compile the operations

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get TF variables
TF_INC=$(python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')
TF_LIB=$(python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())')

# Neighbors op
g++ -std=c++11 -shared tf_neighbors/tf_neighbors.cpp tf_neighbors/neighbors/neighbors.cpp cpp_utils/cloud/cloud.cpp -o tf_neighbors.so -fPIC -I$TF_INC -I$TF_INC/external/nsync/public -L$TF_LIB -ltensorflow_framework -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
g++ -std=c++11 -shared tf_neighbors/tf_batch_neighbors.cpp tf_neighbors/neighbors/neighbors.cpp cpp_utils/cloud/cloud.cpp -o tf_batch_neighbors.so -fPIC -I$TF_INC -I$TF_INC/external/nsync/public -L$TF_LIB -ltensorflow_framework -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

# Subsampling op
g++ -std=c++11 -shared tf_subsampling/tf_subsampling.cpp tf_subsampling/grid_subsampling/grid_subsampling.cpp cpp_utils/cloud/cloud.cpp -o tf_subsampling.so -fPIC -I$TF_INC -I$TF_INC/external/nsync/public -L$TF_LIB -ltensorflow_framework -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
g++ -std=c++11 -shared tf_subsampling/tf_batch_subsampling.cpp tf_subsampling/grid_subsampling/grid_subsampling.cpp cpp_utils/cloud/cloud.cpp -o tf_batch_subsampling.so -fPIC -I$TF_INC -I$TF_INC/external/nsync/public -L$TF_LIB -ltensorflow_framework -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

Within my Dockerfile I attempt to call this script to compile the operations while building the image

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-devel-gpu-py3

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y --fix-missing --no-install-recommends\
    python3-setuptools python3-pip python3-tk

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install numpy scikit-learn psutil matplotlib pyqt5 laspy tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0

COPY . /kpconv

WORKDIR /kpconv/tf_custom_ops
RUN sh compile_op.sh

WORKDIR /kpconv/cpp_wrappers
RUN sh compile_wrappers.sh

WORKDIR /kpconv

# Build
# sudo docker build -t kpconv-test .

# Run
# sudo docker run --rm -it --runtime=nvidia kpconv-test /bin/bash
```

Though no matter what I try (an exhaustive list that I will not add to the content of this question) it always fails to compile the code. Specifically with the exception (or part of it)

```
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

*Though, this isn't necessairly the issue.*

---

I had decided to put this issue on hold for the time being and commented out the lines which `RUN compile_op.sh` in the Dockerfile. This resulted in a successful image build. I then started up the container. After some other work I decided to see what would happen if, within the container, I ran `sh compile_op.sh`. This magically worked without issue.

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it --runtime=nvidia kpconv-test /bin/bash
root@c36376e71177:/kpconv# cd tf_custom_ops/
root@c36376e71177:/kpconv/tf_custom_ops# sh compile_op.sh 
root@c36376e71177:/kpconv/tf_custom_ops#
```

Further evidence this worked is by attempting to start a training run of the neural network by calling one of the provided training scripts in KPConv.

First, without `sh compile_op.sh`

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it --runtime=nvidia kpconv-test /bin/bash
root@64ed930c5aca:/kpconv# python training_ModelNet40.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
<...>
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: tf_custom_ops/tf_neighbors.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@64ed930c5aca:/kpconv#
```

Though after compilation the compiled `.so`s can be imported and the script progresses (I don't actually have the data set)

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it --runtime=nvidia kpconv-test /bin/bash
root@938a9d7bc2b0:/kpconv# cd tf_custom_ops/
root@938a9d7bc2b0:/kpconv/tf_custom_ops# sh compile_op.sh 
root@938a9d7bc2b0:/kpconv/tf_custom_ops# cd ..
root@938a9d7bc2b0:/kpconv# python training_ModelNet40.py 

Dataset Preparation
*******************
<...>
OSError: Data/ModelNet40/modelnet40_normal_resampled/modelnet40_train.txt not found.
root@938a9d7bc2b0:/kpconv#
```

**Is there some fundamental difference between calling `sh compile_op.sh` within the Dockerfile versus within the container that cause the former to fail and the later to be successful?**

---

I have a feeling the answer may lie with the use of `RUN sh ...` within the Dockerfile. Maybe `sh` does not have access to the "correct" `$PATH` or other environment variables during the `docker build` process...?

Comment: Does the container already include g++, because you don't ever install build-essential. I probably don't know enough about the tensorflow package.

Comment: Maybe at the point you try and run the compile the library has not been installed and subsequent action in the docker file install that library.

Answer (score 0):

This all reminds me of compiling ROS in a cloned GitLab project using Dockerfile.

There, I also had to C++ compile, and it was only possible using a `bash` shell, not the `sh` shell, see the example below.

When I got the error `catkin_make: command not found`, it was because I had not [sourced ROS](https://answers.ros.org/question/212492/catkin_make-command-not-found/?answer=212502#post-id-212502).
Sourcing ROS in a Dockerfile must be done by just running it, at least I could not get it to run when adding it to the `.bashrc` (which would be `#RUN /bin/bash -c "echo 'source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc;source ~/.bashrc'` - but does not work). This works instead:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash;\
    cd /rosyard;\
    catkin_make -j8 # compile;\
    echo "source /MY_PROJECT/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc'
```

The last command will source the already compiled ROS at every start of the bash, also when you start a container bash.

Obviously, C++ compiling (catkin_make) works inside the image.
If I build the image without CMD at the end, I have to source the compiled ROS in the container, since it needs to be done at every start of a shell - even if it is just a new shell in the container. The only way to get around that is to start the bash already in the image and use CMD to already source the compiled ROS (untested).

I do not know your project enough to know the source commands, but it seems that you should source before compiling, since C++ compiling in an image works in my case. And you should use `RUN /bin/bash -c "..."` to compile with `bash`, not with `sh`, see more about this difference at [“/bin/sh: 1: MY_COMMAND: not found”](https://superuser.com/questions/1634933/bin-sh-1-my-command-not-found).